# Query on Non Equi joins for Left outer join in Hive

Tags: sql, join, hive, hql, non-equi-join

I am trying a left outer join between two tables with the non equi join condition and hive is not supporting it. Adding the condition in where clause result in data loss. Please let me know if any one have a solution for it. following is sample code snipset

```
Select B.dt ,D.field, sum(B.qty)
from A INNER join B ON A.dt= B.dt
INNER Join C ON B.nbr=C.nbr
LEFT OUTER JOIN D ON A.nbr2=D.Nbr2
AND B.nbr=D.nbr
---Below non equi join not supported
AND B.dt between C.start_date and C.End_Date 
-- Need suggestion of this non equi join.
```

Following is the error for non equi joins in hive :FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10017]: Line 9:4 Both left and right aliases encountered in JOIN 'START_DATE'

Comment: I need D's column i have updated the hql

Answer (score 0):

There is one way to do this in your case.  That is a `union all`/window functions approach.  I *think* this does what you want:

```
with t as (
      select a.nbr2, b.nbr, b.dt, null as end_date, null as field, b.qty
      from A join
           B
           on A.dt = B.dt
      union all
      select d.nrb2, d.nbr, d.start_date, d.end_date, d.field, null
      from D
    )
select dt, (case when dt < d_end_date then d_field end), sum(qty)
from (select t.*, 
             last_value(field, true) over (partition by nbr, nbr2 order by dt) as d_field,
             last_value(end_date, true) over (partition by nbr, nbr2 order by dt) as d_end_date
      from t
     ) t
group by dt, dt, (case when dt < d_end_date then d_field end);
```

I'm not 100% sure this is exactly the same -- for instance, this assumes at most one matching record in D and no overlaps.  But the idea is to interleave the values and use window functions as `last_value()` with the `ignore null`s option to fetch the right value.